# Want to install SUPEE-11086 patch for magento 1.9.2.0 version

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-11086

I want to install SUPEE-11086 patch  Magento 1.9.2.0 version.

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one PATCH_SUPEE-11086_CE_1.9.2.4_v1.sh which is applicable from Magento 1.9.1.0 - 1.9.2.4

Comment: are you sure? this will work proper?

Comment: Yes. I have done the same to apply the patches